# Custom Log in Craft

Tags: plugin-development

Is there any way to create a custom log in Craft? I need to log some actions inside a controller/service in a custom plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in your plugin:

```
ExamplePlugin::log('the is the log message');
```

the log method has the following signature:

```
log($msg, $level = LogLevel::Info, $force = false)
```

documentation [is here](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-baseplugin.html#public-properties)

your log will appear in the app/storage/runtime/logs/pluginname.log

Comment: Do i have to create any class for this to work?

Comment: if you have a custom plugin your will already have a main plugin class in the root of your plugin folder like ExamplePlugin.php this class will extend BasePlugin and thus get the static log function