# Custom plugin log not logging

Tags: craft2, logs, logging

I'm having this weird issue that both of my custom plugin logs are not working but all other third party ones including craft.log work fine. By 'not working' I mean the log file is generated, but empty.

Another weird thing is the issue only happens on production environment. Tested on local environment and staging environment, they all work fine.

I believe I got the code right?

`MyPlugin::log("Errors:\n\n" . print_r($fieldsData, true), LogLevel::Error);`

It's Craft 2 by the way.

Anything ideas?

Comment: Weird... I'm assuming devMode is not enabled in production.  Is it locally and in staging?

Comment: devMode is enabled locally, but disabled on staging and production. Weird, huh? Anyway, forcing log param did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the force parameter to true

```
MyPlugin::log("Errors:\n\n" . print_r($fieldsData, true), LogLevel::Error, true);
```

[Custom Log in Craft](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/custom-log-in-craft)